# obj.hasOwnProperty(prop); prop is not defined

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Такой код выдаёт ошибку, почему (вроде должно быть true)?
Даже если явно задать obj.prop ошибка всё равно та же.

```
var prot = {
  name: "ProtoPro"
};

function F(x) {
  this.prop = x;
};

F.prototype = prot;

var obj = new F(10);
console.log(obj); // ▼F {prop: 10}
                  //    prop: 10
                  //   ▼__proto__: 
                  //      name: "ProtoPro"
                  //     ▶__proto__: Object

console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(name)); // false
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)); // Uncaught ReferenceError: prop is not defined
```

Comment: я вот даже не знаю каким дубликатом лучше закрыть :-)

Comment: и немного поясню: параметром `hasOwnProperty` - **должна быть строка**, а ты пытаешься передать переменные: `name` берется из window, а переменная `prop` не определена, поэтому и получаешь ошибку. Если заменишь на `hasOwnProperty('name')` и `hasOwnProperty('prop')` - все заработает